# Unable to charge and connect a USB device at the same time

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

When I plug in a USB-C cord into my Android phone in my car, I want it to simultaneously charge over fast charging (PD 20W) and also connect to a USB DAC (external sound card). This way I can charge my phone and play music. The issue is that I tried 2 hubs and they both don't allow me to do this. For example, this last one I just bought seems to allow me to do either one or the other. If both things are plugged into it, it only does one thing. If a charger only is plugged in, it charges. If a USB DAC is plugged in, I can play music over it. But I can't do both. Why is this happening? Is this a phone limitation? Is this a hub limitation?

Device: Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite.

OS: MIUI 14.0.2 Android 13 TKQ1.221013.002

USB C Hub: https://a.aliexpress.com/_mPEFojK